# Why there is a "de" in "faire de l'exercice"?

Tags: phrase

Learning several faire related phrases:

```
   Faire une promenade
   Faire le lavage (la lessive)
   Faire une sieste
   Faire le ménage
   Faire l’épicerie
   Faire de l’exercice
```

Could anyone let me know why there is an extra "de" in the "faire de l'exercice"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you could have the sentence without that *de* also:

> faire l'exercice

would mean something like *complete a problem in a homework assignment*, or *do a specific physical exercise*. But it would have to be something specific that's known from the context. In English, it would be *do/solve the problem* or *do this (specific) exercise*.

In contrast,

> faire de l'exercice

is more indefinite, and just means *do physical exercise*. No specific exercise is concerned, one just *exercises*.

Comment: Similar: *faire le ménage*, *faire du ménage*, *faire des ménages*.